# How to create table with dynamically rows and columns with number in React-JS

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr=[]
for(let i=2;i<=10;i=i+2){
  arr[i]=[]
 for(let j=1;j<=20;j=j+2){
  arr[i][j]=i*j;
 }
 console.log(`\n`);
}
console.table(arr);
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

**This Code Correct in JavaScript, But No Idea in React-JS

```
enter code here
```

[How This Table Image Create in React-JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pidjl.png)**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple table example using `map()`

The `map()` method builds the table by looping through all items of the array and returning HTML with the index and string of each array item.

**HTML returned by map()**

```
<tr key={index}>
  <td>
    {index}
  </td>
  <td>
    {str}
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Try the following snippet**

```js
function App(){
  const myArray = ['item zero', 'item one', 'item two']
  
  return[
    <table key='table-key'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>index</th>
          <th>string</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {myArray.map((str, index) => {
        return[
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>
              {index}
            </td>
            <td>
              {str}
            </td>
          </tr> 
          ]
        })}
       </tbody> 
    </table>
  ]
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, But Table Border Not Perfectly Work bro, Please Help Me